# Usage of "schon", "längst" and "tatsächlich"

Tags: difference, adverb

What is the difference between *schon*, *längst* and *tatsächlich*?

> Ich gehe schon/längst/tatsächlich zur Arbeit.

Comment: Please... http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11571410#11571410

Comment: Was sagt denn der Duden, Leo oder ein anderes Lexikon, was der Unterschied sei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ich gehe schon ...":

"schon" is used when you are doing something earlier than pretended.

1a) It is used for the explanation that one is already able/allowed to do something. Like when an infant would say

> "I'm not in kindergarten anymore, I'm *already* going to school" - "Ich gehe *schon* zur Schule"

1b) can also be used when you are earlier in the means of daytime:

> "Wait it's 7am, are you already on your way to work?" - "Yes I'm *already* going to work" (earlier than usual) - "Ich gehe *schon* (früher) zur Arbeit"

---

"Ich gehe längst ...":

like "schon" but way more **exagerated**. Can also be used together.

2a)  Like the kid was very astonished that the others didn't know it **already a long time** is old enough for school.

> I'm *already* going to school, I'm 7!" - "Ich gehe *(schon) längst* zur Schule, ich bin ja schon 7 Jahre alt"

2b) Your wife reminds you that you may be late for work and you respond

> "I'm *already* on my way to work"  - "Ich gehe ja *(schon) längst* zur Arbeit"

---

"Ich gehe tatsächlich ...":

3) "tatsächlich" means "indeed".
The only case when you would say that is, when someone is pretending you are doing something and you agree.

> "Oh it's 8 AM, so you must be on you way to work now" "Yes *indeed* I'm on my way to work (right now)." - "Ja genau, ich gehe *tatsächlich* (gerade) zur Arbeit".